# How use Oauth2 to connect and use facebook marketing api

Tags: facebook, go, oauth-2.0, facebook-access-token, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to use facebook Marketing API.

The problem is I don't know how to perform the request

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    fb "github.com/huandu/facebook"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
 )

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(200)
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, World!")
    })
    http.HandleFunc("/use-fb", FBConnect)
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
        log.Printf("Defaulting to port %s", port)
    }
    log.Println("Listening on port %s", port)
    log.Printf("Open http://localhost:%s in the browser", port)
}
```

And my Fb Connect function,

```
  func goDotEnvVariable(key string) string {

    // load .env file
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error loading .env file")
    }

    return os.Getenv(key)
}

    func FBConnect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var (
        ClientID     = goDotEnvVariable("FB_APP_ID")
        ClientSecret = goDotEnvVariable("FB_KEY_SECRET")
        tokenApp     = goDotEnvVariable("FB_USER_TOKEN")
        //tokenUser = os.Getenv("Fb_user_app")
    )

    fbConfig := &oauth2.Config{

        ClientID:     goDotEnvVariable("FB_APP_ID"), // change this to yours
        ClientSecret: goDotEnvVariable("FB_KEY_SECRET"),
        RedirectURL:  "http://localhost:8080/use-fb", // change this to your webserver adddress
        Scopes:       []string{"email"},
        Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{
            AuthURL:  "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth",
            TokenURL: "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token",
        },
    }
    url := fbConfig.AuthCodeURL("")
    fmt.Println("Config", url)
    var globalApp = fb.New(ClientID, ClientSecret)
    globalApp.EnableAppsecretProof = true
    session := globalApp.Session(tokenApp)
    err = session.Validate()
    fmt.Println(session.Get("/me", nil))

}
```

I don't know how I can use marketing api because we have just A Facebook Graph API SDK in Go but not A Facebook Marketing API SDK.

Comment: I close this question because a huandu package call a deprecated API ( Just marketing API )

Answer (score 0):

You call use Marketing Api with huandu package but you need to change in sessions.go for  getURL function

```
// facebook versioning.
    if session.Version == "" {
        if Version != "" {
            buf.WriteString(Version)
            buf.WriteRune('/')
        }
    } else {
        buf.WriteString(session.Version)
        buf.WriteRune('/')
    }
```

by

```
buf.WriteString("v9.0")
    buf.WriteRune('/')
```

or if facebook change version

```
buf.WriteString("vx.x")
    buf.WriteRune('/')
```

Or when you call your api you write

```
session.Get("/v9.0/me", nil)
```